# Returning string with diacritics

Tags: rest, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2018, fw1

I want to use FW/1 to return a string that looks like this:

```
"Wüf!"

framework.renderData().data("Wüf!").type( "text" );
```

Note that this is not normal FW/1, but REST

When I run this I get

```
WÃ¼f!
```

Postman reports in the headers, `Content-Type` is

```
text/plain;charset=utf-8
```

**Update**

Visual Code Studio reports that the file is `UTF-8`

Also `EncodeForXML()` turns it into

```
W&#xc3;&#xbc;f&#x21;
```

Which is worse

**Update 2**

I tried

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">
<cfscript>
component   accessors="true" output="false" extends="concerns.rest" {

    property    beanFactory;
    property    framework;
```

But I get

[image]

Comment: `WÃ¼f!` is exactly what you'd expect if something was receiving the utf-8 encoded string `Wüf!` but treating it as ANSI. Is it possible there are one or more cfm/cfc source files included elsewhere in your request that are ANSI encoded - eg your appliction.cfc? Have you tried adding the old `<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding = "utf-8">` trick as a workaround?

Comment: See updated question. As for `application.cfc`, there is nothing that sets encoding.

Comment: I was referring to the encoding of the source files, rather than the presence of any code that sets encoding. You stated that _Visual Code Studio reports that the file is UTF-8_ - but what do you get if you check the encoding of every cf file in the request, eg from Notepad++ -> Encoding? There used to be a JVM arg `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` you could use to force utf-8 without updating your source, I don't know whether that still works but could be worth trying if you're on a dev environment. I don't know FW/1 but imagine `cfprocessingdirective` would need to be in `onRequest` or `onRequestStart`